# how to assign variable dynamically?

Tags: mql4

```
int abc1 = 123;
int abc = 456;
int e = 1;
printf (abc+e);
```

supposedly it will output "123", but it fail with error "abc" is not declare.
How to fix the error?

Comment: Tried  `int b = {}; int test = b['abc' + e]; printf (test);` but it come with error "single quoted is needed"

Comment: Use `Print(abc+e)` or `printf("%d",abc+e)` to have no warnings. `int b={}` is incorrect, you can have `int b[]={}` but then need to intialize that array and set its size. `"abc"` is incorrect also, if you need index then `abc+e` is ok

Comment: U are very helpful person, thank you for answering 2 of my questions. Thanks for your helping hand, really appreciate it.

Comment: no problem. welcome to SOF!

Comment: It looks like you are coming from python. MQL has mapping abjects, but they are a pain to work with. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: @DanielKniaz Could you post your comment as the answer?